# Docusign providing an unspecified error with a status code of 400

Tags: docusignapi, connector, sailpoint

Hi when our application connects to DocuSign via the API when calling a specific endpoint, I get an unspecified error message. The endpoint our system calls is: /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{AccountID}/users. The status code returned is a status 400. The logs don't provide many details. Has anyone experienced this issue when calling this endpoint?

We are using SailPoint's IdentityNow connector to make the API call. The API call is used for account aggregation of users of DocuSign onto the SailPoint system. After 799 accounts are aggregated the status 400 error occurs. We expect the connector to pull all 1033 accounts from DocuSign onto SailPoint.

Answer (score 1):

If you executed a large number of calls (799 )  in a short period (les than one hour) you are probably hitting the [API Calls per Hour Limit](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-soap-api/esign101/security/call-limits/).

You should open a case in DocuSign Support to provide your integration key and get confirmation that you are hitting the limit.

The good news is that the hour call count resets every top of the hour, so your code should be able to finish the migration in one hour.

Regards
Adrian
DS

Comment: The limit is 3000 per hour or 500 per 30 seconds (see link i added to Adrian's answer). But having 799 accounts doesn't mean you make only 799 API calls. My guess is you make 3-4 API calls per account and you hit the limit after 799. You may be able to continue running your remaining 234 accounts in the next hour like Adrian said, or if you need everything to run at once you can either try to do only 2 calls per account or put some 1 minute break after each account to slow things down